# Typescript ignores if statement

Tags: typescript

```
let entities: {
  clickPrice: number
} | undefined = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? {
  clickPrice: Math.random()
} : undefined

const clickPrice = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? Math.random() : undefined

type testType = {
  clickPrice: number
}

const test: {
  clickPrice: number
}[] = []

if (entities || clickPrice) {
  test.push({
    clickPrice: entities ? entities.clickPrice : clickPrice
  })
}
```

Why do I get this error:

```
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

on `clickPrice`

```
clickPrice: entities ? entities.clickPrice : clickPrice
```

?
What I want is "If there's `entities`, or `clickPrice`, execute some code, which could use only one of them".
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBCB2YJbxAZwFwQN4CgIQMbDlwGsAFAJ0JDWgFcBbAIxDMwF8IAfCG6AExABmcaCF4QAvBACyAQzAALAHRkZfAPZ0AFAEoIAPkkAGRQFYIAfgzY8BYuUppZC5at4adbCGh78hI3piYuGrQSJD4hKQUuCAS0nJKKupaugYQxmaWTomu7rrefILCooFgAJ4ADrFgyGAAKpWxklg4EXbRVBC0jMxsgcGhkDVhaC02kfYx1PRMLKwA2gC6cUuBcAIQmjDwiEicXG1RlLpjw2CKFTRI8ppjrbZHU1CwCHDIFs87b0iKh5OxaD%20HWsrG0bCAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the section on type narrowing (specifically ["control flow analysis"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis)), you can see how TypeScript handles types. In short, TypeScript can narrow `entities`, and it can narrow `clickPrice`, but it can't narrow the expression `entities || clickPrice` in a way that is helpful to you.

You'll have to break it out, at minimal expense to readability:

```
if (entities) {
  test.push({clickPrice: entities.clickPrice});
} else if (clickPrice) {
  test.push({clickPrice});
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBCB2YJbxAZwFwQN4CgIQMbDlwGsAFAJ0JDWgFcBbAIxDMwF8IAfCG6AExABmcaCF4QAvBACyAQzAALAHRkZfAPZ0AFAEoIAPkkAGRQFYIAfgzY8BYuUppZC5at4adbCGh78hI3piYuGrQSJD4hKQUuCAS0nJKKupaugYQxmaWTomu7rrefILCooFgAJ4ADrFgyGAAKpWxklg4EXbRVBC0jMxsgcGhkDVhaC02kfYx1PRMLKwA2gC6cUuBcAIQmjDwiEi6Y8NgihU0SPKa6G1RDlCwCHDIileTIKzaANyeIMBIseuazw6+2sh2Op3Ol1s1xib0+rCAA)

Answer (score 0):

Because your type clearly defines this property as number only:

```
type testType = {
  clickPrice: number
}
```

However, your code states that if the random number (0-1) is bigger than 0.5, do another random or return undefined if it's not:

```
const clickPrice = Math.random() >= 0.5 ? Math.random() : undefined
```

You need to either update the type to support undefined or return a valid number instead.

Comment: But I push only if there's no undefined - either entities(with required clickPrice), or clickPrice itself.  If they're both undefined, code never executes

Comment: Try console.log('test', test) at the end of code block - you'll see, that sometimes it's empty array([])

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `as as number` for `clickPrice` because it might be undefined.

```
if (entities || clickPrice) {
  test.push({
    clickPrice: entities ? entities.clickPrice : clickPrice as number
  })
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=50&pln=19&pc=60#code/DYUwLgBCB2YJbxAZwFwQN4CgIQMbDlwGsAFAJ0JDWgFcBbAIxDMwF8IAfCG6AExABmcaCF4QAvBACyAQzAALAHRkZfAPZ0AFAEoIAPkkAGRQFYIAfgzY8BYuUppZC5at4adbCGh78hI3piYuGrQSJD4hKQUuCAS0nJKKupaugYQxmaWTomu7rrefILCooFgAJ4ADrFgyGAAKpWxklg4EXbRVBC0jMwQbIHBoZA1YWgtNpH2MdT0TCysANoAunHLgXACEJow8IhInFxtUZS64yNgihU0SPKa4622x9NQsAhwyBYvu%209IikdTsTQ-w6EBk%2026c2srG0bCAA) is working one